# WSO2 IS 5.4.0: Using the username as attribute in SAML asserton

Tags: wso2, saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

Scenario:

- WSO2 Identity Server 5.4.0 configured as SAML IDP.
- A third party application configured as SAML Service Provider.
- WSO2 IS uses MySQL as the JDBC user store

The SAML SP requires username, firstname and lastname as ATTRIBUTES in the SAML assertion.
The SAML SP claim configuration is set as follows

- firstname -> http://wso2.org/claims/givenname
- lastname  -> http://wso2.org/claims/lastname
- username  -> http://wso2.org/claims/username

firstname and lastname are sent in the SAML assertion as expected, whereas
username is **not** sent in the SAML assertion.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: Further investigation showed that the username is not listed in the CLAIMS table UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE and as such may not be accessible via a claim mapping defined in WSO2 IS. Interestingly in OIDC the username is returned as the sub claim which is actually mapped to http://wso2.org/claims/username

Any hint and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid?

Comment: In default setup wso2.org/claims/userid maps to scimId.   No, that won't work

Comment: What is you subject claim URI set to? Do you get username as the subject in SAML assertion ?

Comment: Yes, the username is correctly sent as NameID. Subject Claim URI in Claim Configuration is still set to default (no attribute is selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable scim for JDBCUserStoreManager. In user-mgt.xml file makes SCIMEnabled property to true as follows.

```
<Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
```

Then try the SAML flow.

Comment: SCIMEnabled was already set to true. I do think that is not related to the actual problem.

Comment: I suspect that scim disabled is the problem because,when you add a user, the username value is assigned to username claim with SCIMUserOperationEVentListener. In that case, if you didn't enable the SCIM, the username claim won't get assigned with the username. But in OIDC sub claim is getting the username from logged in user not from username claim. You could refer https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/OAuth2Service.java#L496-L497.

Comment: I cannot find anything like SCIMUserOperationEventListener in the config or in the code.  I just wonder: What you describe would actually only help when users get created via SCIM? What about users created via UI or SOAP?

Comment: The above code is for adding sub-claim for OIDC. You can find the code related to  SCIMUserOperationListener in https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-provisioning-scim/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/scim/common/listener/SCIMUserOperationListener.java#L136-L142. You can find the config of SCIMUserOperationListener in identity.xml file. No, even though user created through UI still the SCIMUserOperationListener will be invoked in order to have consistency between adding a user through SCIM, SOAP,UI.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not seeing that SCIMUserOperationListener is adding the username claim in a persistent way in order to get picked up by SAML.

Comment: Need to correct my last comment. I found it in SCIM2 SCIMUserOperationListener  not in SCIM SCIMUserOperationListener. I have enabled the listener and the uid attribute gets populated in the database (along other SCIM attributes). I have marked the answer as a solution although I see it as a WORKAROUND with some side effects. It is also not consistent with using a LDAP UserStore in WSO2.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I would like to know what are u meant by "It is also not consistent with using an LDAP UserStore in WSO2"?. Could you please clarify more on this.

Comment: I mean the SCIM workaround is not needed as long as you are using an LDAP (as the uid attribute is available as is)